# Getting a template argument is invalid error? Why?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

For some reason, I keep getting a "template agrument 1 is invalid error" when compiling my code. I'm not sure why. I'm trying to create a linked list using templates. Here is my code

When running my main method where I introduce the class as:

```
Dlist<L> list;
```

Then I try to implement a few of the functions.

The error I get is:

```
 Dlist<L> list;  template agrument 1 is invalid. 

                      ^
```

HELP

ListNode.H

```
#ifndef LISTNODE_H
#define LISTNODE_H

#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;

template <class L>
class ListNode
{
    public:
    L data;
    ListNode *prev;
    ListNode *next;


    ListNode(L d);
    ListNode();
    ~ListNode();
};

template <class L>
ListNode<L>::ListNode()//blank constructor
{

}

template <class L> 
ListNode<L>::ListNode(L d)//overloaded constructor
{
    next = NULL;
    prev = NULL;
    data = d;
}

template <class L>
ListNode<L>::~ListNode()//deconstructor
{
    next = NULL;
    prev = NULL;
}

#endif
```

DList.h

```
#ifndef DLIST_H
#define DLIST_H

#include <iostream>
#include "ListNode.h"

using namespace std;

template <class L>
class Dlist
{
    private:
        ListNode<L>* front;
        ListNode<L>* back;
        unsigned int size;

    public:
        Dlist();//constructor
        ~Dlist();//destructor

        //insert and remove functions
        void insertFront(L data);
        int removeFront();
        void insertBack(L data);
        int removeBack();
        ListNode<L>* removeAt(L pos);

        //other functions
        bool isEmpty();
        int find(L val);
        int getFront();
        int getBack();
        unsigned int getSize();
        void printList();


};

template <class L>
Dlist<L>::Dlist()
{
    size = 0;
    front = NULL;
    back = NULL;
}

template <class L>
Dlist<L>::~Dlist()
{
    if(front != NULL)
    {
        delete front;
    }
}

template <class L>
void Dlist<L>::insertFront(L data)
{
    ListNode<L> *node = new ListNode<L>(data);
    if (size = 0)
    {
        back = node;
    }
    else
    {
        front->prev=node;
        node->next=front;
    }
    size++;
    front = node;
}

template <class L>
int Dlist<L>::removeFront()
{
    ListNode<L> *temp = front;
    if(front->next = NULL)
    {
        back = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        front->next->prev = NULL;
        front->next = NULL;
    }
    front = front->next;
    int val = temp->data;
    delete temp;
    --size;
    return val;
}

template <class L>
void Dlist<L>::insertBack(L data)
{
    ListNode<L> *node = new ListNode<L>(data);
    if (size == 0)
    {
        front = node;
    }
    else
    {
        back->next = node;
        node->prev = back;
    }
    back = node;
    size++;
}

template <class L>
int Dlist<L>::removeBack()
{
    ListNode<L> *temp = back;
    if(back->prev = NULL)
    {
        front = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        back->prev->next = NULL;
    }
    back = back->prev;
    int val = temp->data;
    delete temp;
    --size;
    return val;
}

template <class L>
ListNode<L>* Dlist<L>::removeAt(L key)
{
    ListNode<L>* curr = front;

    while(curr->data != key)
    {
        curr=curr->next;
        if (curr == NULL)
        {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    //found the key
    if(curr == front)
    {
        front=curr->next;
}
    else
    {
        curr->prev->next = curr->next;
    }
    if(curr==back)
    {
        back = curr->prev;
    }
    else
    {
        curr->next->prev = curr->prev;
    }
    curr->next=NULL;
    curr->prev = NULL;
    size--;

    return curr;
}

template <class L>
unsigned int Dlist<L>::getSize()
{
    return size;
}

template <class L>
void Dlist<L>::printList()
{
    ListNode<L>* curr = front;

    while(curr != NULL)
    {
        cout<< curr->data << endl;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}

template <class L>
int Dlist<L>::getFront()
{
    return front;
}

template <class L>
int Dlist<L>::getBack()
{
    return back;
}
#endif
```

Comment: Due to formatting error, that was not clear from your post.  Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Either way, I just put Dlist<int> and I no longer get the error, so I'm hoping that flies. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can not use the template class as you are trying.

Dlist< L> list;

As L is not a valid data type. Valid data type includes built-in or user defined data type.
"L" you are using it as a template so you can use it only inside the template class.

The above statement would be valid if you define your own class 'L' like below:

```
class L
{
    int a;
};
```

Hope that helps.